# what is wrong in my function?

Tags: c, function

I'm using code:: blocks and when I compiled this program it did not show any error but when i run it it says convolution.exe has stopped working (i.e., I saved it as convolution.c), I don't know what's happening, can anyone help me with this, my code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define array_len(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(double))
void convolution(double *signal, int nt, double *wind, int r, double *rm)
{

  int i,j;
  double copy[nt];
  for(i=0; i<nt; i++)
  {
      copy[i] = signal[i];
  }

  int l = (nt+r-1);
  for(i=r;i<=l;i++)
  {
      wind[i]=0;
  }
  for(i=nt;i<=l;i++)
  {
      copy[i]=0;
  }
  for(i=0;i<=l;i++)
  {
      rm[i]=0;
      for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
      {
         rm[i] = (rm[i]+(copy[j]*wind[i-j]) );
      }

  }
}

void main()
{
  double a[1020];
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<1020; i++)
  {
      a[i] = 1;
  }
  int la = array_len(a);
  printf("\nc1\t%d",la);

  double b[1020];
  for(i=0; i<1020; i++)
  {
      b[i] = 1;
  }
  int lb = array_len(b);
  printf("\nc2\t%d\n",lb);

  double r[la+lb-1];
  int lr = array_len(r);
  printf("\nc3\t%d\n",lr);

  printf("entering convolution\n");
  convolution(a,la,b,lb,r);
  printf("in main\n\n");

  for(i=0;i<(50);i++)
  {
      printf("rm[%d]=%lf\n",i,r[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770078/what-is-the-mistake-in-this-program

Comment: You need to use a *debugger*, not Stack Overflow. Only turn to Stack Overflow once you've narrowed down the error using a debugger and *still* can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You probably should learn how to use debugger - debug it step by step and see where it crashes

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've debugged it n found that when I call the function convolution in main it crashes

Comment: Use a debugger before posting. Also, keep in mind that void main() is not good practice. Consider the use of int main()

Answer (score 1):

A few other issues:

Your `printf` is looking for `long int` but you're passing it `int`. Change `%ld` to `%d` in the `main()` function.

Update `main()` not to be `void` but to have an `int` return type (like `int main()`) and also return something at the end just before the closing bracket (normally `return 0;` is put in case the execution has proceeded smoothly).

EDIT: I just want to mention that these are things that you can easily fix by taking care of the warnings that the compiler prints (I'm sure they were there).

EDIT: This is what my compiler printed with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags enabled (I'm using GCC under Linux):

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:

test.c:43:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

test.c:51:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

test.c:55:3: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

test.c:34:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
```

Comment: Thanks for your info but I didn't receive any warnings when compiled

Comment: That's odd, what compiler are you using? Cygwin? I've updated my post, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770078/what-is-the-mistake-in-this-program).
Anyway, the problem is that you access your arrays out of bounds. Please be careful not to access an array within its size which was given at the time of initialization/declaration. To solve your problem, modify the function `convolution` as follows:

```
void convolution(double *signal, int nt, double *wind, int r, double *rm)
{

  int i,j;
  int l = (nt+r-1);
  double signal1[l];
  double signal2[l];
  for(i=0; i<l; i++)
  {
      if (i < nt)
          signal1[i] = signal[i];
      else
          signal1[i] = 0;
      if (i < r)
          signal2[i] = wind[i];
      else
          signal2[i] = 0;
  }
  for(i=0;i<=l;i++)
  {
      rm[i]=0;
      for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
      {
         rm[i] = (rm[i]+(signal1[j]*signal2[i-j]) );
      }
  }
}
```